# Using Dynamic Pivot/Unpivot to display correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I believe I will have to use both a Pivot and a UnPivot to get the data that I want.

My current data looks like this:

```
var_date    var_attribute   var_out_of_ad   var_per_ad
9/4/2012    Aux1            0               0
9/5/2012    Aux1            0               0
9/4/2012    Aux2            1680            0.733333333
9/5/2012    Aux2            1680            0.733333333
9/4/2012    Aux3            1500            0.791666667
9/5/2012    Aux3            1500            0.791666667
9/4/2012    Aux4            0               0
9/5/2012    Aux4            0               0
9/4/2012    Aux5            0               0
9/5/2012    Aux5            0               0
9/4/2012    Aux6            26640           0.766929134
9/5/2012    Aux6            26640           0.766929134
9/4/2012    Aux7            28800           0
9/5/2012    Aux7            28800           0
9/4/2012    Aux8            3600            0
9/5/2012    Aux8            3600            0
```

I want to be able to break apart by Aux Code (which will by dynamic) the columns `var_out_of_ad` and `var_per_ad` so I would like my data to look like this:

```
var_date  Aux1_per   Aux1_out   Aux2_per   Aux2_out ...
9/4/2012  0          0           .733      1680
9/5/2012  0          0           .733      1680
```

I have put the testing data into a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f06d/1 as well as all of the work I have done with the dynamic pivot.

Can someone please guide me as to what to do next? I am lost.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to `PIVOT` two columns of data, you need to `UNPIVOT` first, then apply a `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = Stuff((Select distinct ',' 
                           + QuoteName([var_attribute] + x.type) 
                    from mytable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select '_per' type
                      union all
                      select '_out' type
                    ) x
            FOR XML Path(''), Type
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'select var_date, ' + @colsPivot + '
              from
              (
                select var_date, 
                  val,
                  case col when ''var_out_of_ad'' 
                              then VAR_ATTRIBUTE + ''_out''  
                          when ''var_per_ad'' 
                              then VAR_ATTRIBUTE + ''_per'' end var_attribute 
                from
                (
                  select var_date, var_attribute,
                      cast(var_out_of_ad as float) var_out_of_ad,
                      var_per_ad
                  from mytable
                ) x
                unpivot
                (
                  val
                  for col in (var_out_of_ad, var_per_ad)
                ) u
              ) x1
              pivot
              (
                max(val)
                for var_attribute in ('+@colsPivot +')
              )p'

exec(@query)
```

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f06d/14)