# Dynamic Pivot (row to columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, unpivot

I have a `Table1`:

```
ID Instance Name Size Tech
 1   0       D1  123   ABC
 1   1       D2  234   CDV
 2   2       D3  234   CDV
 2   3       D4  345   SDF
```

I need the resultset using Dynamic `PIVOT` to look like along with the headers:

```
ID | Instance0_Name | Instance0_Size | Instance0_Tech | Instance1_Name | Instance1_Size | Instance1_tech
1  | D1             | 123            | ABC            | D2             | 234            | CDV
```

Any help would be appreciated. using Sql Server 2008.

Sorry for the earlier post.

Comment: Do you want the `ID` to be displayed in the final result?  You have different `IDs` so which one do you want?

Comment: I just realized that.Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do you want each of the separate "ID" values to be on a separate line with all the instances associated with that ID pivoted out? This would end up looking really ugly as a resultset since the naming is based on the instance value and the instance values appear to be unique. It would lead to there being one value per column and NULLs for all the instances that it doesn't apply to on the row. Depending on the dataset size you might run into a column limitation issue.

Comment: The idea behind this query (which has to also be applied to other tables in the database and combine all of them) is to get ONE table with all the fields present in the database. RE-ENGINEER back to a format -a CSV file where people can do their own testing(pivot/chart) since right now I don't have a front end for the database.  The CSV file is going to be large. The NULLs are fine. The column limitation -highest I think would be 250 at the most.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Dynamic Pivot/Unpivot to display correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531522/using-dynamic-pivot-unpivot-to-display-correctly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your desired output is not exactly clear, but you can use the both the `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT` function to get the result

If you know the number of columns, then you can hard code the values:

```
select *
from
(
  select id, 
    'Instance'+cast(instance as varchar(10))+'_'+col col, 
    value
  from 
  (
    select id, 
      Instance, 
      Name, 
      cast(Size as varchar(50)) Size,
      Tech
    from yourtable
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (Name, Size, Tech)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(value) 
  for col in
    ([Instance0_Name], [Instance0_Size], [Instance0_Tech], 
     [Instance1_Name], [Instance1_Size], [Instance1_Tech], 
     [Instance2_Name], [Instance2_Size], [Instance2_Tech], 
     [Instance3_Name], [Instance3_Size], [Instance3_Tech])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b2a4/2)

Then if you have an unknown number of values, you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
                      + quotename('Instance'+ cast(instance as varchar(10))+'_'+c.name)
                    from yourtable t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                    where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('id', 'instance')
                    group by t.instance, c.name
                    order by t.instance
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select id, 
          ''Instance''+cast(instance as varchar(10))+''_''+col col, 
          value
        from 
        (
          select id, 
            Instance, 
            Name, 
            cast(Size as varchar(50)) Size,
            Tech
          from yourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in (Name, Size, Tech)
        ) u 
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db967/2)

If the result is not correct, then please edit your OP and post the result that you expect from both of the Ids you provided.