# how to create temp table while Joining multiple tables that have to be PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have similar 3-4 scripts for different tables to dynamically PIVOT as previously posted 
[Dynamic Pivot (row to columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224371/dynamic-pivot-row-to-columns/14224646#14224646)

Goals: 
 - Create a excel file Joining all the fields from the PIVOTed tables(all the rows from each table)

Steps:

- Create separate temp tables for each set (after Pivoting on different tables)
- JOIN all the temp tables on column ID
- SELECT columns from the resultset(all temp tables)

**Would like to know if there is a better way to create a temp table using a procedure for joining all the tables for the final select.

**I tried creating temp table but got the error :invalid object

as a result of the accepted answer in the previous post**

```
INSERT into #T1 execute('execute' + @query )
select * from #T1
```

**

---

**Case 1: Pivot on yourtable**

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
                      + quotename('Instance'+ cast(instance as varchar(10))+'_'+c.name)
                    from yourtable t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                    where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('id', 'instance')
                    group by t.instance, c.name
                    order by t.instance
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select id, 
          ''Instance''+cast(instance as varchar(10))+''_''+col col, 
          value
        from 
        (
          select id, 
            Instance, 
            Name, 
            cast(Size as varchar(50)) Size,
            Tech
          from yourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in (Name, Size, Tech)
        ) u 
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

--exec(@query)
```

**I tried creating temp table but got the error :invalid object
as a result of the accepted answer in the previous post**

```
INSERT into #T1 execute('execute' + @query )
select * from #T1
```

**Case 2: Same code PIVOT for MYtable**

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
                      + quotename('Instance'+ cast(instance as varchar(10))+'_'+c.name)
                    from mytable t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                    where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('id', 'instance')
                    group by t.instance, c.name
                    order by t.instance
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select id, 
          ''Instance''+cast(instance as varchar(10))+''_''+col col, 
          value
        from 
        (
          select id, 
            Instance, 
            Name, 
            cast(Size as varchar(50)) Size,
            Tech
          from mytable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in (Name, Size, Tech)
        ) u 
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'


    INSERT into #T2 execute('execute' + @query2 )
    select * from #T2
```

** Case 3:Same code PIVOT for OurTable**

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
                      + quotename('Instance'+ cast(instance as varchar(10))+'_'+c.name)
                    from ourtable t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                    where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('id', 'instance')
                    group by t.instance, c.name
                    order by t.instance
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
        select id, 
          ''Instance''+cast(instance as varchar(10))+''_''+col col, 
          value
        from 
        (
          select id, 
            Instance, 
            Name, 
            cast(Size as varchar(50)) Size,
            Tech
          from ourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in (Name, Size, Tech)
        ) u 
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'


   INSERT into #T3 execute('execute' + @query2 )
    select * from #T3
```

**FINAL SELECT:**

```
select * from #T1
inner join #T1.id=#T2.id
inner join #T1.id=#T3.id
```

Comment: Can you please post the full code you tried? Also try to modify the [**working demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db967/2) from the previous question explaining your issues. This will be very helpful.

Comment: Are `#t1`, `#t2` and `#t3` already defined? Or are you trying to create the temp tables?

Comment: No they cannot be defined earlier as they depend on the dynamic resultset from each of the Pivot cases.I am trying to save each of the Pivot results into their respective temp tables. I have not used table variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you are using dynamic sql and you want to insert that into a temp table for use later on.  Here are the issues with that:

- The temp table cannot be created before because the number of columns is unknown.
- A temp table created inside the dynamic SQL will be out of scope for use after.  This issue exists when you create a local temp table (those that begin with a single # sign)

If you want to join these multiple tables together than you could create a global temp table or a real table (not temp) that can be created in during the dynamic SQL execution and used outside of that scope.

Using the code from the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224371/dynamic-pivot-row-to-columns/14224646#14224646) I altered it with a table being created:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
                      + quotename('Instance'+ cast(instance as varchar(10))+'_'+c.name)
                    from yourtable t
                    cross apply sys.columns as C
                    where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('id', 'instance')
                    group by t.instance, c.name
                    order by t.instance
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select *
     into ##t1  -- < create global temp table or real table without the ##
      from
      (
        select id, 
          ''Instance''+cast(instance as varchar(10))+''_''+col col, 
          value
        from 
        (
          select id, 
            Instance, 
            Name, 
            cast(Size as varchar(50)) Size,
            Tech
          from yourtable
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          value
          for col in (Name, Size, Tech)
        ) u 
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(value)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query);

select * from ##t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db967/21).

This will allow you to join the multiple tables together.

Reference:

- [Temporary Tables in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)

Comment: thanks alot for showing the use of global temp tables here. Before I saw this solution I had just added: set @query = 'select * into #temp1 ... and at the End I added to the stmt ' drop table T1; select * into T1 from #temp1;' which actually created a table. But looks like I will be going to goahead with the actual tables since they will be used for reporting purposes.Thanks again for helping me solve this issue.

Comment: @Rodricks Yes creating a table instead of a temp table might be better. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I tried the above on another table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/100bd/5 but could not get it to work, I keep getting syntax error.