# How to Make a pivot out of one table in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

How can I achieve the second picture using T-Sql language deriving from the first picture which is a database table.

Encircled w/ red will be becoming rows and there values will be put on the corresponding date from the `slver_date` and that slver_date header which is highlighted w/ yellow will become columns containing the date.

The slvr_date values per item are the same count, so I could say that it is not dynamic.

and also the mapping is as follows:

oh_qty = starting onhand

firm_po = Firm Purchase Order

act_demand = firm_demand

tot_plan_trans_out = Planned Transfer Out

foh_ss = FOH-SS

ss_qrt = Safety Stock Qty

planned_purch = Planned Purchase

[image: table1]

Expected Output
[image: TobeLayout]

Someone told me to use Pivot, but I don't have any experience using it.

Comment: There are 8 columns in the sample, but only 7 rows. Can you clarify which columns get mapped to which "My Category" row? Also, please put your sample data as text. Much easier to copy/paste than an image.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: This looks like *unpivoting* followed by pivoting. There are examples of both out there; what about the (literally) 100's of examples didn't you understand? The fact you want a column per date though means you (presumably) want a dynamic pivot afterwards. I **strongly** suggest that is a job for your presentation layer.

Comment: This someone is right, this is a unpivot (of categories) + dynamic pivot (of dates) kind of problem, answer to which has been posted before.

Comment: Additionally, I get the gist. But it's much more helpful if your expected results correlate exactly to what you want to get from the sample. There are a bunch of other columns in that expected (screenshot!) that don't relate to the input you've provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Dynamic Pivot/Unpivot to display correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531522/using-dynamic-pivot-unpivot-to-display-correctly)

Comment: This is **not possible** in one step. The SQL language has a _strict rule_: you **must** know the number of columns at query compile time, _before looking at **any** table data_. If you have to look in the table to know about your columns, as we do here with `slvr_date`, you will need to do this over three steps: `1)` Write a query to get the column list. `2)` Use results from 1 to build a new query dynamically. `3)` Run the query from 2.

Comment: I suspect the query would take a date range as input, and could generate the dates and dynamic pivot columns from that range. This can be done in one step using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example of what pivot + unpivot combo might look like:

```sql
create table #example (id int, date datetime, a int, b int, c int, d int)

insert into #example
values  (1, '20200101', 1,2,3,4)
,   (1, '20200102', 5,6,7,8)
,   (1, '20200103', 9,0,1,2)
,   (2, '20230103', 1,0,1,0)

declare @dates nvarchar(max)
,   @dates_pivot nvarchar(max)
,   @sql nvarchar(max)
select  @dates = STRING_AGG('pv.' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), date, 126)) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(replace(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), date, 6), ' ', '-')), ',') within group(order by date)
,   @dates_pivot = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), date, 126)), ',') within group(order by date)
FROm    (
    SELECT  date
    FROM    #example
    GROUP BY date
    ) d

select @sql = N'
    select id, col AS category,' + @dates + N'
    from #example
    unpivot (value for col in (a,b,c,d)) upv
    pivot (max(value) for date in (' + @dates_pivot + N')) pv
    order by id, col
    '

exec(@sql)
```

@dates_pivot will contains the unique "pivoted" dates, which goes to the pivot operator

@dates is similar, but also contains the alias for the headers if one wants those

Then we build dynamic sql which first unpivots columns a,b,c,d into value and finally pivots it back.

I couldn't get the colors working, but you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: thanks sir, this works like a charm. :)